# How do I, instead of copying a file/folder into a linked folder, move it to that link?

Tags: windows, storage, drive

So, I recently have had a problem! My C: drive is pretty full. I have the D: drive, and I have a folder there, where I could put my Desktop's files on. I'm running `Windows`, specifically `Windows 10`. So, what I wanted to ask is - is there a way to NOT copy files from other drives but **just move them**? I have shortcuts to all of my folders (Files, photos, etc...) which go on my Desktop, but due to low space I have the files on the other drive. It copies the files there instead of moving them.

This question should've gone on superuser lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way drives are organized all you can really do is copy a file from one drive to another, then delete the original. You could theoretically have a tool that treats that two-step operation as if it were a simple move, but there's nothing I'm aware of that does that.

Update:

You could use symbolic links (like shortcuts, but better for some purposes) to make files on your D: drive behave in many ways as if they were on your C: drive:

`mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]] <Link> <Target>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/